# Trouble establishing connection to server with PyMySQL [WinError 10054]

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Pretty new to both Python and SQL, so please excuse my noobishness. We have a server at my company that I'm trying to connect to through some python code. I have the correct IP address and logon credentials, and I can connect to it in SQL Server Management Studio without any issues, but I can't connect to it through PyCharm's database feature or through my code. I'm running python 3.6 if that makes a difference.

This is the code that I'm running (I've omitted the server ip address and logon credentials for security):

```
    import pymysql

    db = pymysql.connect(host='server ip', 
                         port=1433, 
                         user='username', 
                         passwd='password', 
                         db='Development DB')

    cursor = db.cursor()        
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print("Database version : %s" % data)
    db.close()
```

When I run the code, after about 2 minutes of nothing happening I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1021, in _read_bytes
    data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aubrey_s/PycharmProjects/Drawings_Converter/Drawings_Converter.py", line 5, in <module>
    db = pymysql.connect(host='ip address', port=1433, user='username', passwd='password', db='Development DB')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 706, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 931, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1245, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 987, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1029, in _read_bytes
    "Lost connection to MySQL server during query (%s)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)')
```

From what I can understand, it looks like a connection was established, but the server forced it to close after a while. Can anyone offer me some more insight into what the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removed the sql server tag as this is obviously a mysql issue.

Comment: did you check privileges

Comment: How would I check the privileges? I just wrote some similar code in Java and it connected just fine.

Answer (score -2):

As I wrote in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192851/7426596), you may want to try using [pymssql](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/), in case your database is not a MySQL DB but a Microsoft SQL DB.

Comment: It is explicitly tagged as a MySQL database, also the error message shows this as well. This is not the answer here.